# How to create a variable for a function in Roblox (Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local colorwheel = script.Parent
local clickdetector = colorwheel.ClickDetector
local barlight = workspace.barlight:GetChildren()

--attempting to establish function as variable--
local rightmouse = function onMouseClick()
        print(" turned the lights off")
        barlight.Transparency = 1
end

local leftmouse = function onMouseClick()   
        print(" turned the lights on")
        barlight.Transparency = 0
end

clickdetector.RightMouseClick:connect(rightmouse)
clickdetector.MouseClick:connect(leftmouse)
```

Im trying to create a function so that when the model "colorwheel" is clicked, it changes the transparent property of the "barlight" model. I want to establish two separate variables for the onMouseClick() function so I can change the way the function behaves based on what mouse button clicked it. One to turn the light it on and one to turn it off. All of this is being done within a server script rather than a local one (*not sure if that means anything*)

```
local rightmouse = function onMouseClick()
local leftmouse = function onMouseClick()
```

When I try to make onMouseclick() a variable, it gets a red underline right under the word itself, and tells me "*Workspace.barlight wheel.Script:5: Expected '(' when parsing function, got 'onMouseClick'"* Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function onMouseClick() end` defines a function. It does not resolve to a function value. Hence you cannot assign it to a local variable as attempted in

```
local rightmouse = function onMouseClick()
        print(" turned the lights off")
        barlight.Transparency = 1
end
```

This is incorrect syntax. You can define a function two ways:

```
local function myFunction() end
```

or

```
local myFunction = function () end
```

So either

```
local rightmouse = function ()
        print(" turned the lights off")
        barlight.Transparency = 1
end
```

If you want the function's name to be `rightmouse`, or

```
local function onMouseClick()
        print(" turned the lights off")
        barlight.Transparency = 1
end
```

if you want the functions name to be `onMouseClick`